# Преимущество задания такого тега table?

Tags: html, table, contenteditable

Всем привет, в чем преимущество задания такого тега `table` в современных браузерах?

```
<table width="100%" 
       border="0" 
       cellspacing="0" 
       cellpadding="0" 
       height="100%" style="min-width: 780px;">
```

Как считается `table[Attributes Style]` в Chrome? Надо-ли убирать доктайп в начале html кода?

Answer (score 0):

Это устаревший способ (HTML4, сейчас используем HTML 5). В современном стандарте необходимо все атрибуты ответственные за стили переносить в css.

В HTML5 это должно выглядит примерно так:

```
<table class='table_1' style="min-width: 780px;">
```

> как считается table[Attributes Style] в Chrome?

Также как и в других современных браузерах. Эти стили css приоритетного типа. Рекомендуется избегать такого способа по возможности.

> надо-ли убирать доктайп в начале html кода?

Он нужен, чтобы указать версию документа. Рекомендуется оставить

Comment: Это https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp?

Comment: как в html5 сделать резиновую таблицу чтоб футер примыкался к низу браузера?

Comment: Да это оно. Это уже другой вопрос. Ответ на него можно найти в поисковиках. Первая ссылка в гугле http://htmlbook.ru/layout/fiksirovannyy-podval

Comment: это с DIV, надо с TABLE. заранее спасибо

Comment: необязательно, можно указать в ширину в %. Правда не для всех таблиц подходит